# Second screen does not work initially

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, display

When I first boot my second monitor (an old Dell P2311H) shows "The current input timing is not supported by the monitor display. Please change your input timing to 1920x1080@60Hz".

I have checked the "screen display" settings and indeed that is what is selected on that screen.

When I switch to "single display" and then back to "join displays" the problem goes away and the screen works as expected. However this is not ideal because this loses the relative positioning of the displays.

I am using the nouveau driver for a GeForce 2070 (the proprietary drivers don't work at all). Both displays are connected to this graphics card, one via DVI (the one that presents with this issue) and the other via HDMI.

Comment: Not sure if this matters, but did you turn your monitors on before you booted your Ubuntu machine?  Or did you boot your machine first and turned on the second monitor while at the login screen?  As a suggestion, you might want to consider posting a new question about using the proprietary drives -- maybe someone else can help you with that and solve your monitor problem at the same time...

Comment: @Ray the monitor is powered on from system boot time, but it's not the main monitor so is in powersaving mode until I log on my user. I'm not sure whether its better to use the proprietary drivers, I wasn't too fussed about it but it might be worth a go if by getting them to work it solves this issue as well. When I tried using them I was getting "Unknown monitor" for my main monitor (it still worked) but the 2nd screen could not be detected at all so maybe there is something there.

Comment: Personally, I have had less problems with proprietary drivers in the long run.  That is, sometimes it doesn't work at first but I get less problems later on.  But yes -- it might not solve your problem in the end.  But if no one else has a suggest for you, it might be worth a try...